# How to iterate through td in a tbody?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<table> 
    <tbody id="SAMPLETBODY">
        <tr>
            <td>TEST1</td>
            <td>TEST2</td>
            <td>TEST3</td>
            <td>TEST4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the code above, I want to iterate through the td's, since iterating through tbodies in a table is like this:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('firstTable');
for(int i = 0; i < table1.tBodies.length; i++) {
    /*DO SOMETHING HERE*/
}
```

How can I do it in td inside tbodies?

EDIT:

I have multiple tbodies in the table, I have already tried some codes that is similar (It iterated through all tbodies) and posted here before I asked the question.

EDIT AGAIN:

final code:

```
function sampleFunc() {
    var x = "";
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#SAMPLETBODY td'), i;
    for(i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
        x = x + tds[i].innerHTML;
    }
    return x;
}
```

thanks to:rink.attendant.6

Comment: why use jquery for something so simple?

Comment: @sevenseacat  1. Probably using elsewhere on the page 2.Can write it in one line of code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('tbody td'), i;
for(i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
    // do something here
}
```

If you wish to restrict it to a certain table, for instance, `#firstTable`, you will need to specify that:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#firstTable tbody td');
```

Just noticed that you have an ID on your `tbody`, so the selector would look like this for your specific `tbody`:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#SAMPLETBODY td');
```

Comment: he is not using jquery

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is a JavaScript function that works with IE 8+ and other browsers

Answer (score 3):

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('firstTable');
```

Here it returns table with id firstTable

Then using that get all `td` within the table1 like

```
var tds = table1.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Now you can iterate over each td like

```
for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    console.log(tds[i])
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/MJdBQ/1/)

Comment: what if there is a tfoot in the table??

Answer (score 3):

Using `getElementsByTagName('td')` or `querySelectorAll` is the most reasonable approach, but since you already know about `tbodies`, it might be interesting for you to learn about `rows` and `cells` as well.

A `tbody` element has a property `rows`, which is a collection of `tr` elements, i.e. the rows it contains (not surprising, right?). Each `tr` element in return as a property `cells`, which is a collection of `td` elements (no surprise here either).

So *technically* you could do

```
for(var i = 0; i < table1.tBodies.length; i++) {
  var tbody =  table1.tBodies[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < tbody.rows.length; j++) {
    var row = tbody.rows[j];
    for (var k = 0; k < row.cells.length; k++) {
      var cell = row.cells[k];
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

But such a nested for loop is hard to read and maintain. The other answers show much better solutions.

You can learn about the properties of [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableSectionElement), [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) and [`td`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) in the MDN documentation.

Comment: I have been trying to make use `:not` selector along with `querySelectorAll` something like `var table1 = document.getElementById('firstTable');
var tds = table1.querySelectorAll('td:not(tfoot td)');
` but I couldn't find a way to do it.  Can you share your thoughts on this approach(possible/not)?

Comment: @Praveen: Unlike with jQuery, the CSS `:not` selector only accepts ["simple selectors"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors), e.g. type, class, id, attribute, not selectors which express relationship between nodes (descendant, child, sibling). So you'd have to use `querySelectorAll('tbody td')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `rows` an `cells` arrays:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('firstTable');

for (var i = 0; i < table1.tBodies.length; i++) {

    var rows = table1.tBodies[i].rows;
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {

        var cells = rows[j].cells;
        for (var k = 0; k < cells.length; k++) {
            console.log(cells[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/6Xbre/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the humble getElementsByTagName():

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('SAMPLETBODY'),
cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var k = 0; k < cells.length; ++k) {
    // do stuff with cells[k];
}
```

Comment: This will find all TDs, not just inside tbody

Comment: @SajithNair Where else than inside tbody would you find td?

Comment: `tfoot` as well. It's really straightforward to adjust though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$("td", firstTable).each(function() {...}
```

With javascript only. Try this...
Edit:

```
            var table = document.getElementById('SAMPLETBODY'),
            cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

            for (var k = 0; k < cells.length; ++k) {
                // do stuff with cells[k];
                alert(cells[k].innerHTML);
            }
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery.

Comment: What is `$`? It's not a native JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for example:

```
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tds = tbody.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var node in tds){
    console.log(tds[node])
}
```

There are different methods to do this things, you can use document.getElementById (if you have table or tbody with id), document.getElementsByClassName in case when table or tbody have class name etc.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xnmNc/)

Comment: what if there is a tfoot in the table??

Answer (score 1):

give a id for your table  and use javascript for this

```
<table id="table_id" >
<script>
var e1 = document.getElementById('table_id');
for(int i = 0; i < e1.tBodies.length; i++) {

}
</script>
</table>
```

Comment: this is outside by the table . i am going to tell the hint

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('SAMPLETBODY');
var tds = table1.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    alert(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
```